# Filter a dropdown list

Tags: newform

I have a custom list, and I'm trying to achieve a  filtered dropdown in the newform.aspx of the list. So lets say I have 2 dropdowns, and if a user choose 'fruits' value in the first, the second dropdown will show 'apple','orange'...
And if he chooses 'games', the second will show 'gta v','battlefield 3'...

How can I do that? I have created  custom lists with all the fruits and another with all the games.. but I need the second dropdown to change his values when the first dropdown value is changed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cascade Dropdown Cross-Site Lookup](http://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/348401) to achieve that.

There are also [solution](http://www.spums.be/?p=241) using InfoPath forms that I found online but I have not tested myself.